# Can we add a rEFInd tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags

REFInd is a commonly used boot manager developed by Rod Smith. I think that it should be added due to its eminence. I can't add it myself because I don't have the rep. I'd like if someone added the tag to this question (by me) https://askubuntu.com/posts/441514/edit.